# What is assembly cmp instruction comparing exactly?

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64

I'm learning assembly language and encountered a problem that I don't know even how to ask Google. I'm using gdb to debug simple c program.

I have following code:

```
cmp    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0xc]
jle    0x400cc2
```

Breaking on the cmp instruction, I'm checking values for the comparison:

```
p/d $eax // 1000
x/d $rbp-0xc //-24
```

So I assume, that the jump won't happen. But after going to the next step - I can see that ZF flag is set. 
Could  someone please explain in simple words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have done everything right, except you didn't provide MCVE and didn't show gdb log. You are correct that ZF should NOT be set. Maybe you used gdb wrong.

```
6           mov dword [rbp-0xc], -24
(gdb) s
7           mov eax, 1000
(gdb)
8           cmp eax, dword [rbp-0xc]
(gdb)
9           jle foo
(gdb) p/d $eax
$1 = 1000
(gdb) x/wd $rbp-0xc
0x7fffffffe254: -24
(gdb) p $eflags
$2 = [ CF PF IF ]
```

Indeed, the jump will **not** be taken.

Since you insist you are seeing ZF set, that probably means your `x/d` is using a byte size instead of the proper dword. If you have 1000 in memory that looks like `e8 03 00 00` since x86 is little endian. If you print just the lowest byte as signed it will come out as -24. Use `x/wd` to force dword size, otherwise gdb defaults to the most recently used size which may not be appropriate.

Comment: Well, I'm confused. I tryed few times, and it's always same thing. Before cmp `$eflags = [ IF ]`, after si command `$eflags= [ PF ZF IF ]`

Comment: Edit your question with complete gdb log. Also, use `x/wd` to make sure you are printing 4 byte integers. Note that 1000 is `e8 03 00 00` and -24 is `e8 ff ff ff` so if you only print a single byte, you may get a result of -24 even though 1000 is in memory.

Comment: Omg, `x/wd $rbp-0xc` prints me 1000. Now everything makes sense. I'm not that familiar with gdb, and i's hard to ask google such specific issue. Thanks!